# Inject angular module dynamically to main module based on user role

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

we are using angularJS for our webapplication. We need implement following scenario using angular SPA application.

We have two angular modules i.e. moduleA, moduleB. Both modules can be standalone websites and moduleB is pluggable website based on user role.

If user has RoleA he can Access moduleA, if he has role as RoleB he can access moduleB. If user has RoleC then he can access both modules i.e. moduleA and moduleB.

Now based on user role how we can inject module dependency to main module?

e.g.

```
var moduleA = angular.module("moduleA", []) 
var moduleB = angular.module("moduleB", []) 

**For roleA**
var mainModule = angular.module("sampleApp", ["moduleA"])   

**For roleB**
var mainModule = angular.module("sampleApp", ["moduleB"])

**For roleC**
var mainModule = angular.module("sampleApp", ["moduleA","moduleB"])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get the point: why not using `if (role == roleA) angular.module('sampleApp', ['moduleA']) else if ...` ?

Comment: I think you should edit your question. I think someone will vote to close it as not clear what you're asking. Do you even know the role during the config phase?